# Recover a source file after it has been written on

Tags: file, restore, recovery, data-recovery, file-recovery

One of my friends had launched this command:

```
gcc -o source.c source
```

Instead of:

```
gcc -o source source.c
```

And now he has lost the code that he's been working on for few days.
Is there a chance to recover the code?

It's a Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 1).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "photorec", [available for redhat](http://lintut.com/photorec-recovery-deleted-files-onrhel-centos-fedora-ubuntu-mint-linux/) which sometimles give some good results